# Conversion of Excel / Access / Text file into UTF-16LE format

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-16

I need to write a converter which will accept as input Excel, Access or Text file and convert it to **UTF-16LE** format. I would like to integrate that module into some PHP code which already exists and which acts as a 'management interface' to an underlying MS SQL Server application.

Any ideas, tips or maybe already written code?

---

### **Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

You need two files for converting a text file into excel file. One would be your text file, say **test.txt** and an excel file **newfile.xls**.
The below script can be executed to obtain the desired result.

```
<?php
    $csv_output .= "\n";   
    $filename = "newfile.xls"; //Name of the excel file needed     
    $textfiledata = file_get_contents('test.txt'); //Name of the txt file
    $csv_output .= $textfiledata;

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".xls");
    header("Content-disposition: filename=" . $filename . ".xls");
    print $csv_output;
    exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at PHP's [iconv library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.iconv.php). I have used it in a similar situation before where I needed to access/convert Excel input before inserting it into my database.